# Launch Runnable Jar from Web Start

Tags: jar, java-web-start, jnlp

This is my first time trying to use Web Start, and I am trying to launch my runnable jar. I get the following error from my webpage as I click the link to launch the jar. Can anyone help me out? The Notepad example from the tutorial works fine from another link on the test page (JNLP and jar in same folder as I have too). The jar and jnlp are definitely in the same folder, yet the jar cannot be found. Thanks in advance.

Folder Structure:

```
/MyApp
/MyApp/MyApp.jnlp
/MyApp/MyApp.jar
```

JNLP File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localhost/MyApp" href="MyApp.jnlp">
   <information>
      <title>MyApp Demo</title>
      <vendor>Company Name</vendor>
   </information>
   <resources>     
    <jar href="MyApp.jar"/>   
    <j2se version="1.5+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
   </resources>
   <application-desc main-class="MyAppMain"> 
    <argument>arg1</argument> 
    <argument>arg2</argument> 
  </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Exception:

```
com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource: http://localhost/MyApp/MyApp.jar
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload.downloadJarFiles(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload.downloadEagerorAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.downloadResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareLaunchFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Wrapped Exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost/MyApp/MyApp.jar
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor2.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doGetRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload.downloadJarFiles(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload.downloadEagerorAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.downloadResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareLaunchFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost/MyApp/MyApp.jar
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    ... 20 more
```

Console:

```
Java Web Start 1.6.0_15
Using JRE version 1.6.0_15-b03 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Documents and Settings\username
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
p:   reload proxy configuration
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------
#### Java Web Start Error:
#### Unable to load resource: http://localhost/MyApp/MyApp.jar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my reson for why this file will not load. This was a permissions error. The account trying to access the JAR file didnt have windows permissions. I had created the JAR from Eclipse and exported it to my Desktop, then copied it over into the JNLP directory. Those permissions were not changed for the JAR after the copy/paste.