# java web start jar file not found via remote access

Tags: java, java-web-start, filenotfoundexception

I've got a problem by running a Java Web Start application remotely. When run locally, there's not this kind of problem. The problem is, that the jar file is not deployed to the local temp folder (jnlp file is deployed correctly), so the FileNotFound exception is thrown to the Java Console.

Can anyone help?

index.html:

```
<body>
<!-- ... -->
<script src=
  "http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script>
    // using JavaScript to get location of JNLP
    // file relative to HTML page
    var dir = location.href.substring(0,
        location.href.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    var url = dir + "myapp.jnlp";
    deployJava.createWebStartLaunchButton(url, '1.6.0');
</script>
<!-- ... -->
```

jnlp file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="" href="">
<information>
    <title>mytitle</title>
    <vendor>mycompany</vendor>
    <offline-allowed/>
</information>
<resources>
    <!-- Application Resources -->
    <j2se version="1.6+" href=
       "http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="myapp.jar"
        main="true" />

</resources>
<application-desc
     name="My Application">
 </application-desc>
 <update check="background"/>
```

Java console throws:
Exception:

```
com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource: file:/C:/DOCUME~1/myhome/LOCALS~1/Temp/myapp.jar
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload$DownloadTask.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Wrapped exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\DOCUME~1\myhome\LOCALS~1\Temp\myapp.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doGetRequest(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload$DownloadTask.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260950/launch-runnable-jar-from-web-start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *must* specify proper values for href and codebase for Java Web Start to work properly.  The reason is that the launcher may choose to invoke a new JVM given a cached copy of the JNLP script with no ties back to the original.

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Can you please provide more details on what exactly need to be done?

Comment: @G.G. Open a new question with a minimal, complete example showing the problem.